# Work done in moving a charge from infinity to a point near an infinitely large, uniformly charged, thin plane sheet

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, work

This is a word for word reproduction of a question on a test:

> An infinitely large thin plane sheet has a uniform surface charge
>   density $\sigma$. Obtain the expression for the amount of work done in
>   bringing a point charge $q$ from infinity to a point at a distance of $r$ in front of the charged plane sheet.

Here is what I did:

Taking the potential at $\infty$ to be $0$, and the potential at $r$ units away to be $\frac{\sigma*r}{2\epsilon}$, the work done is the change in potential energy which gives the answer as
$\frac{q*r*\sigma}{2\epsilon}$

But according to the marking scheme the answer is:[image]

[[This](https://www.quora.com/How-can-we-calculate-the-work-done-in-bringing-a-charge-from-infinity-to-a-point-near-a-large-plane-charged-sheet)] link on quora has both answers :|

I think the marking scheme is wrong but I can't figure out where. I think it is because $V=\frac{\sigma*r}{2\epsilon}$ is just an approximation near the surface of the sheet.

Comment: If the potential at distance $r$ away is $\sigma r/2\epsilon_0$, then the potential at infinite distance can’t be zero.

Comment: @G.Smith as I mentioned isn't $V=\frac{\sigma*r}{2\epsilon}$ an approximation near a surface ? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: No, it’s not an approximation.

Comment: The sign is wrong though.

Comment: Don’t believe anything you read on Quora. I’ve seen a lot of nonsense there.

Comment: Think about how peculiar it would be for the potential to be increasing/decreasing linearly but then turn around and go to zero at infinity. It would mean that at some magic distance the potential would have a maximum/minimum. But with an infinite plane there is no length scale. Where would that maximum/minimum be?

Comment: As Juan’s answer says, the field can be found with Gauss’ Law and is uniform (independent of distance) on each side.

Comment: https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/302l/lectures/node27.html

Comment: http://www.phys.uri.edu/gerhard/PHY204/tsl92.pdf

Comment: You mean "infinite, uniformly charged sheet".

Answer (score 4):

I think it’s because given that the sheet is infinitely charged, the expression for the potential at r is not an approximation and it can be deduced using gauss law. The sheet creates an uniform electric field at any distance, therefore the work would be infinite.

Answer (score 0):

> I think the marking scheme is wrong but I can't figure out where.I think it is because $V=\frac{\sigma*r}{2\epsilon}$
>   is just an approximation near the surface of the sheet.

For an infinite flat surface the distance of any point which is a finite distance from the surface is infinitely small when compared with the size of the surface ie any point is "near the surface of the sheet".

In effect for a charge to get to any finite distance from the charged surface it will have to travel an infinite distance and so do an infinite amount of work.